# Access parent scope in child directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am trying to access parents directive scope in child directive.
I want child directive to inherit parents scope.

```
    function parent() {
        return {
            scope: {
                attribute: '=attribute'
            },
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E'
        }
    }
```

Above code represents parent directive.

```
function child() {
    return {
        require: '^parent',
        scope: {
            attribute: '=attribute', 
            attribute2: '='
        }
        restrict: 'E'
    }
}
```

Above code represents child directive.
I would like child directive to inherit **attribute** from parent directive if it is provided in html, but I want to be able to use it as non-nested directive as well.

```
<parent attribute='attr'>
    <child attribute2='attr2'></child>
<parent>

<child attribute='attr' attribute2='attr2'></child>
```

Above code is something I would like to achieve.

Comment: If you want the directive to inherit from the parent use `scope: true`. If you want no scope on the directive use `scope: false`. For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Comment: Two-way (`"="`) binding is deprecated. Using it will make migrating to Angular 2+ difficult as Angular 2+ does not have two-way binding.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).